# Zapier - Get MySQL data to Alexa

Tags: mysql, alexa-skills-kit, zapier

I'm trying to get Zapier to get data from a MySQL database to Alexa.
The test action gets a row of data: Six values. But, I can't publish the zap.

Steps:

1. Trigger Phrase Spoken in Amazon Alexa - gets green tick
   Alexa app chosen

Trigger Phrase Spoken Three phrases

2. Find Row via Custom Query in MySQL - gets green tick
   Tested and a full row of six values are received

The Zap status says I need to add another step.

I want Alexa to read out the values.

Any idea what that step may be?

Comment: I think the problem is I'm on a free plan and MySQL is a Premium and needs to be paid for - The thing is I don't want to pay for something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot speak to the features or limitations of Zapier, if I understand correctly, you want to create an Alexa skill which reads data from an existing MySQL database correct?

If so, and that MySQL database is already internet accessible, then you could avoid Zapier entirely by having your skill's back-end code (typically hosted on an AWS Lambda function) connect to your MySQL database directly.

Now, the code to achieve this will vary depending upon the language you're using but I've provided links to two popular packages for the most common Alexa skill languages, Python and Node.js.

Python: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-introduction.html

Node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql